# Wordpress php echo link not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am just trying to add links in the footer credits with a simple echo. The links show up in the footer but when you click on them you are given a 404 page. The pages do exist and if you type them in manually or use a html link the pages appear. What am I doing wrong??

```
add_filter( 'genesis_footer_creds_text', 'custom_footer_creds_text' );
        function custom_footer_creds_text() {
            echo '<div class="creds"><p>';
            echo 'Copyright &copy; ';
            echo date('Y');
            echo ' &middot; <a href="/privacy-policy/‎">Privacy Policy</a> &middot; <a href="/about-us/‎">Terms of Use</a>';
            echo '</p></div>';
        }
```

Outputs:

```
    <div class="creds">
    <p>Copyright © 2013 · <a href="http://speakeasy.stagetheweb.com/privacy-policy/‎">Privacy Policy</a> · <a href="http://speakeasy.stagetheweb.com/terms-of-use/‎">Terms of Use</a>
    </p></div>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like once it is outputted to the page?

Comment: `<div class="creds"><p>Copyright © 2013 · <a href="http://speakeasy.stagetheweb.com/privacy-policy/‎">Privacy Policy</a> · <a href="http://speakeasy.stagetheweb.com/terms-of-use/‎">Terms of Use</a></p></div>`

Comment: The `add_filter()` wordpress function may be killing it. Have you tried adding the echo code directly into your `footer.php` template file?

Comment: I tried adding the code to the footer.php with the same result. The links appear but then output 404...is there something wrong with wordpress and echo-ing out links?

Comment: No not usually, are you using Multisite by any chance?

Comment: No multisite plugins used.

Comment: Looks like you fixed the problem. What did the trick?

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that you copy-pasted the url from somewhere, right?

Try rewriting the whole line by hand, as you may have copied some invisible characters without your knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
echo ' &middot; <a href="/privacy-policy/‎">Privacy Policy</a> &middot; <a href="/about-us/‎">Terms of Use</a>';
```

with:

```
echo ' &middot; <a href="' . get_site_url() . '/privacy-policy/‎">Privacy Policy</a> &middot; <a href="' . get_site_url() . '/about-us/‎">Terms of Use</a>';
```

You can also try `home_url()` instead of `get_site_url()`.  If this doesn't fix it, there is some other factor we don't know about influencing things.  If this doesn't help please post the HTML output (e.g. view source) of the footer as seen on the live site so we can see the URL being generated.

Comment: This is the output.  

`<div class="creds"><p>Copyright © 2013 · <a href="http://speakeasy.stagetheweb.com/privacy-policy/‎">Privacy Policy</a> · <a href="http://speakeasy.stagetheweb.com/terms-of-use/‎">Terms of Use</a></p></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a space in the url. I clicked on the link http://speakeasy.stagetheweb.com/privacy-policy/ and your page came up properly. But when I click the link there appears to be a tab or `&nbsp;` or something in the address bar.

So maybe try:

```
$privacylink = rtrim("/privacy-policy/");

echo ' &middot; <a href="' .$privacylink. '‎">Privacy Policy</a> &middot;';
```

If that doesn't work, it may be something in your `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 1):

See, There is an invalid character in your code.

[image]

This may work. I just removed the invalid character in your code. Replace the block with this.

```
add_filter( 'genesis_footer_creds_text', 'custom_footer_creds_text' );
        function custom_footer_creds_text() {
            echo '<div class="creds"><p>';
            echo 'Copyright &copy; ';
            echo date('Y');
            echo ' &middot; <a href="/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a> &middot; <a href="/about-us/">Terms of Use</a>';
            echo '</p></div>';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a filter, you should return the value. Try:

```
add_filter( 'genesis_footer_creds_text', 'custom_footer_creds_text' );
function custom_footer_creds_text( $creds )
{
    $creds = '';
    $creds .= '<div class="creds"><p>';
    $creds .= 'Copyright &copy; ';
    $creds .= date( 'Y' );
    $creds .= ' &middot; <a href="' . home_url( '/privacy-policy/' ) . '‎">Privacy Policy</a> &middot; <a href="' . home_url( '/about-us/‎' ) . '">Terms of Use</a>';
    $creds .= '</p></div>';

    return $creds;
}
```

Comment: try to echo, change the last line: `echo $creds;`

Comment: echo $creds; is a no go as well. It is crazy for the link not to work...it's there, it's correct, and I can click on it but returns 404 every time.